# Unable to connect to Postgres with client certificate

Tags: windows, postgresql

I've installed Postgres 10.1 on a Windows server, and it's running as a Windows service. It's installed into `%APPDATA%` for the Local System user, which is the user account the Window service is running with:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\My App Database
```

My server-side SSL certs are in this same directory, and my postgresql.conf is configured to find them:

```
ssl_cert_file = 'db.crt'
ssl_key_file = 'db.key'
ssl_ca_file = 'ca.crt'
```

My pg_hba.conf file seems to be configured correctly:

```
hostssl     my-database         my-username         0.0.0.0/0               cert clientcert=1 map=my-username
```

I'm trying to connect with the `psql` command line tool:

```
psql "postgresql://my-username@localhost/my-database?sslmode=verify-full&sslkey=C:\MyDir\MyClientCert.key&sslcert=C:\MyDir\MyClientCert.crt"
```

but I get this error:

```
psql: root certificate file "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming/postgresql/root.crt" does not exist Either provide the file or change sslmode to disable server certificate verification.
```

I can't find any reference to `root.crt` in my config, and I've no idea why it's looking in `%APPDATA%\postgresql`, rather than the configured PGDATA directory, `%APPDATA%\My App Database`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting with `sslmode=verify-full` implies that you want the client to verify the server's certificate which requires specifying a "root certificate" using "sslrootcert" connection parameter or "PGSSLROOTCERT" environment variable. I would hazard to guess that it is supplying %APPDATA%\postgres\root.crt as the default.

The error message supplies your solution, but I suspect you misunderstood -- this is a client error not a server error, the server configuration is immaterial.

> Either provide the file or change sslmode to disable server certificate verification.

You can change sslmode to "require" or provide a root cert.

Comment: You're right, I had thought this was a server error, and hadn't considered it might be a client error!